# Alguien sabe como resolver esta duda de web scrapping con Python de una pagina web hecha en php?

Tags: python, web

Estoy haciendo web scrapping con Python de una pagina para automatizar clicks y funciona. EL problema lo tengo cuando quiero descargar informacion (ya sea datos o las imagenes de esa pagina)  ya que toda la informacion que veo en internet me pide que ponga la url de la que descargarme la info.  La cosa es que esta pagina muestra tras validarme como pagina de inicio la siguiente direccion:
https://paginawebalaquelehagoscrapping.es/front.php? la cual tiene un formulario y al rellenarlo y darle a submit en vez de mostrarse otra url en la barra de direcciones se muestra exactamente la misma, de forma que al hacer scrapping a la web solo me hace de la pagina de inicio,  no del resto de las paginas de la web, ya que donde quiera que pique en esa web siempre me muestra https://paginawebalaquelehagoscrapping.es/front.php? en la barra de direcciones.  No se si les sirve de ayuda mi explicacion.  Ah!! puedo tambien decir que al analizar el codigo fuente de esa pagina y analizar que hace el boton submit veo esto:

```
    <input type="submit" value="Generar" />
</form>
    <input type="button" name="volver" value="Volver" onclick="window.location='front.php?mvc_controller_actions_Action=inicio&mvc_controller_actions_Action_nombre=inicio'"/>

<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/lib/datePicketEstadisticas.js"></script>
```

Alguien sabe como poder hacer web scrapping en esas condiciones?   MILLONES DE GRACIAS!!

Comment: Aunque la dirección no cambie, al darle a *submit* aparecerán nuevos elementos en la página y desaparecerán otros. Comprueba manualmente qué modificaciones hay en la página desde la consola del navegador y una vez las reconozcas automatiza esa comprobación en tu código. Puede ser algo tan simple como que existe una nueva etiqueta *div* con cierto *id*, o que el botón *submit* ya no está en la página. Para hacerlo puedes usar *selenium*.

Comment: Muchas gracias.  Voy a probar a ver que cosas aparecen y aparecen.